# compiler error in a c program:indirection on type void*

Tags: c, compiler-errors

```
void main()
{
void *v;
int integer=2;
int *i=&integer;
v=i;
printf("%d",(int*)*v);
}
```

this simple program will result in a compiler error saying:

```
Compiler Error. We cannot apply indirection on type void*
```

what exact does this error mean?

Comment: Please stop using `void main()`.

Comment: yeah sure but my main concern is about the warning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means exactly what it says. The error is triggered by the `*v` subexpression used in your code.

Unary operator `*` in C is often called *indirection* operator or *dereference* operator. In this case the compiler is telling you that it is illegal to apply unary `*` to a pointer of type `void *`.

Comment: i know this will solve but i was more interested in knowing about the error...anyways thanks for ur comment.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot dereference pointers to `void` (i.e., `void *`). They point to a memory location holding unknown data so the compiler doesn't know how to access/modify that memory.

Comment: just something to add.
the compiler doesn't know what are "void" type so it dont know hot to retrieve them (as oppose to compiler expecting 4 bytes for integer, 8 bytes for double and etc), hence you will get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
printf("%d",(int*)*v);
```

to this:

```
printf("%d",*(int*)v);
```